# How to remove default hover and active from an textfield in Material UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

**i'm building a login form and i used material ui textfield, but the textfield's have a default hover and active and i can't remove them.**

This is my password textfield:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSiXt.png)]

With hover:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhqQO.png)]

Active:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fir8E.png)]

I've tried this:

```
'& .MuiInput-underline:hover:before':
{
    border: 'none !important'
},

'&:hover fieldset': {
      borderColor: 'grey',
    },

'& .MuiInput-underline:hover:before':
{
    border: 'none !important'
},
```

I just need to remove the hover and active

Comment: Have you tried to use 'makeStyles'  from "@material-ui/core/styles" ?

Comment: not yet, but thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can use makeStyles like this:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    '& .MuiInput-underline:before': {
      border: 'none',
    },
    '&:hover .MuiInput-underline:before': {
      border: 'none',
    },
    '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
      border: 'none',
    },
  },
});

export default function Form() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
      <TextField
        className={classes.root}
        label="Password"
        type="password"
      />
  );
}
```

Comment: didn't work, but thanks

Comment: @Werthis, can you explain why/how this works, perhaps link to a functional example?